# Set App to run on iPhone 5+

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, app-store-connect

Really simple question but can't find a answer anywhere. How do I set it so my app (iOS App Store) can only be downloaded by iPhone 5+? e.g iPhone 5, iPhone 5s, iPhone 6 and iPhone 6 Plus only. No iPhone 4s or lower.

Comment: you should lock it by logical reasons based on device capability ...see capabilities list you can use for that https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/DeviceInformation/Reference/iOSDeviceCompatibility/DeviceCompatibilityMatrix/DeviceCompatibilityMatrix.html

Answer (score 3):

There is no option for that. There is only option where you can set minimum iOS version.

You can set minimum iOS version from Deployment Target option.

[image]

Comment: is there any way to do that through setting minimun ios, etc.?

Comment: @markD Since the iPhone 4S supports iOS 8, there is no way to restrict it from accessing your app based on OS version. If the iPhone 4S doesn't support future versions of iOS and the iPhone 5 does, then you'll be able to restrict access.

Comment: @markD no, there isn't. You are allowed to lock your app down by software version and hardware capabilities (eg, a camera app can block devices without a camera), but you can't do it based on model number. You need to find a way to make your device run on a 4S, or else Apple will reject it during app review (eg, if it crashes with an out of memory error while they're testing it). Also, customers will leave 1 star reviews if Apple doesn't pick up the crash.